# How can I delay a function with parameter?

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

I am trying to make a game, where the machine takes a while to respond, so the user actually knows the machine is 'deciding' its move.
I need to use the `setTimeout()` method, but I want to specify a parameter to my function.

Example: `setTimeout(myFunction('p'), 1000);`.
The problem is that when I specify the parameter, the function runs perfectly fine, but there´s no delay.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `setTimeout(myFunction('p'), 1000);`, `myFunction('p')` is evaluated and then `setTimeout(returnValueOfMyFunction, 1000)` is evaluated.

This code will run the anonymous function at the correct time:

```
setTimeout(function (){myFunction('p')}, 1000);
```

Comment: @AndréHelena If my answer helped you, can you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your function like this, so after the time, it will be executed:

`setTimeout(myFunction.bind(this, 'p'), 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the function call with parameters in another parameterless function definition.

Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction('p');
}, 1000);
```